# SQL column naming best practice, should I use abbreviation?

Tags: sql

I want to which is, in your opinion, the best practice for name SQL columns.
Example: Let's say that i have two columns name `referenceTransactionId and source`
now there is another way to write this like `refTxnId and src`

which one is the better way and why? Is it because of the memory usage or because of the readability?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practices for column naming in Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664017/best-practices-for-column-naming-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a matter of opinion, I am going to answer anyway.  If you are going to design a new database, write out all the names completely.  Why?

- The name is unambiguous.  You'll notice that sites such as Wikipedia spell out complete names, as do standards such as time zones ("America/New_York").
- Using a standard like the complete name means that users don't have to "think" about what the column might be called.
- Nowadays, people type much faster than they used to.  For those that don't, type ahead and menus provide assistance.
- Primary keys and foreign keys, to the extent possible, should have the same name.  So, I suspect that `referenceTransactionId` should simply be `transactionId` if it is referencing the `Transactions` table.

This comes from the "friction" of using multiple databases and having to figure out what a column name is.