# MySQL naming conventions, should field name include the table name?

Tags: php, mysql, database, naming-conventions

A friend told me that I should include the table name in the field name of the same table, and I'm wondering why? And should it be like this?
Example:

```
(Table) Users  
(Fields) user_id, username, password, last_login_time
```

I see that the prefix 'user_' is meaningless since I know it's already for a user. But I'd like to hear from you too.
note: I'm programming in php, mysql.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529863/do-you-prefer-verbose-naming-when-it-comes-to-database-columns/529962#529962

Comment: I'm using Doctrine-Project (an ORM framework), and it uses like this:
one(User)-to-one(Picture): 
User[id, name, age, picture_id],   
Picture[id, filename, file]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I agree with you. The only place I am tempted to put the table name or a shortened form of it is on primary and foreign keys or if the "natural" name is a keyword.

```
Users: id or user_id, username, password, last_login_time
Post: id or post_id, user_id, post_date, content
```

I generally use 'id' as the primary key field name but in this case I think user_id and post_id are perfectly OK too. Note that the post date was called 'post_date" because 'date' is a keyword.

At least that's my convention. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: One advantage of having `user_id` instead of `id` on primary and foreign keys is that it makes NATURAL joins a breeze.

Answer (score 11):

I see no reason to include the table name, it's superfluous. In the queries you can refer to the fields as <table name>.<field name> anyway (eg. "user.id").

Comment: @Omar Dolaimy: Your being "really new" has nothing to do with this answer.  Consider deleting your comment.

Answer (score 5):

With generic fields like 'id' and 'name', it's good to put the table name in.

The reason is it can be confusing when writing joins across multiple tables.

It's personal preference, really, but that is the reasoning behind it (and I always do it this way).

Whatever method you choose, make sure it is consistent within the project.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I don't add table names for field names in the main table but when using it as a foreign field in another table, I will prefix it with the name of the source table. e.g. The id field on the users table will be called id, but on the comments table it, where comments are linked to the user who posted them, it will be user_id.

This I picked up from CakePHP's naming scheme and I think it's pretty neat.

Comment: This is pretty common (I follow this practice). Interestingly, it's also an argument against table names in column names -- or at least not compatible with doing so as the naming scheme would start to get confusing at first glance.

Answer (score 2):

Prefixing the column name with the table name is a way of guaranteeing unique column names, which makes joining easier.

But it is a tiresome practice, especially if when we have long table names.  It's generally easier to just use aliases when appropriate.  Besides, it doesn't help when we are self-joining.

As a data modeller I do find it hard to be consistent all the time.  With ID columns I theoretically prefer to have just `ID` but I usually find I have tables with columns called `USER_ID`, `ORDER_ID`, etc.

There are scenarios where it can be positively beneficial to use a common column name across multiple tables.  For instance, when a logical super-type/sub-type relationship has been rendered as just the child tables it is useful to retain the super-type's column on all the sub-type tables (e.g. `ITEM_STATUS`) instead of renaming it for each sub-type (`ORDER_ITEM_STATUS`, `INVOICE_ITEM_STATUS`, etc).  This is particularly true when they are enums with a common set of values.

Answer (score 1):

For example, your database has tables which store information about Sales and Human resource departments, you could name all your tables related to Sales department as shown below:

SL_NewLeads
SL_Territories
SL_TerritoriesManagers

You could name all your tables related to Human resources department as shown below:

HR_Candidates
HR_PremierInstitutes
HR_InterviewSchedules

This kind of naming convention makes sure, all the related tables are grouped together when you list all your tables in alphabetical order. However, if your database deals with only one logical group of tables, you need not use this naming convention.

Note that, sometimes you end up vertically partitioning tables into two or more tables, though these partitions effectively represent the same entity. In this case, append a word that best identifies the partition, to the entity name

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a reason for that kind of naming, especially when it comes to fields, you're likely to join on. In MySQL at least, you can use the `USING` keyword instead of `ON`, then `users u JOIN posts p ON p.user_id = u.id` becomes `users u JOIN posts p USING(user_id)` which is cleaner IMO.

Regarding other types of fields, you may benefit when selecting `*`, because you wouldn't have to specify the list of the fields you need and stay sure of which field comes from which table. But generally the usage `SELECT *` is discouraged on performance and mainenance grounds, so I consider prefixing such fields with table name a bad practice, although it may differ from application to application.

Comment: Agreed, provided that your only use case is hand written sql. An SQL wrapper and/or ORM solution would have foo.id with related table fkey as bar.fooID. I'm migrating a hand coded DB (chock full o' clean JOIN .. USING ..) to ScalaQuery. If needing to drop down to manual SQL, statements will now be in the form of SELECT baz FROM foo f JOIN bar b ON f.id = b.fooID.  Certainly not as clean, but running MySQL & Jedis together with a functional SQL wrapper like SQ means strongly typed queries without the overhead of a full blown ORM like Hibernate. Fast & fun, get on the TypeSafe train ;-)

Comment: Actually, upon further reflection, this response gets a +1 from me. You can have your cake and eat it too. Create domain specific pkeys & fkeys a la userID, orderID. That allows for semantically meaningful field selection (e.g alias.fooID vs alias.id as fooID) and clean natural joins when needing to drop down to manual sql. Then, at wrapper/ORM layer just use domain.id convention since you're working with objects anyway (i.e. no point in writing foo.fooID, just say foo.id)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the conclusion is:
If the field name is unique across tables - prefix with table name.  If the field name has the potential to be duplicated in other tables, name it unique.

I found field names such as "img, address, phone, year" since different tables may include different images, addresses, phone numbers, and years.

Answer (score 0):

We should define primary keys with prefix of tablename.

We should use use_id instead if id and post_id instead of just id.

**Benefits**:-

**1)** Easily Readable

**2)** Easily differentiate in join queries. We can minimize the use of alias in query.

**user table : user_id(PK)**

**post table : post_id(PK) user_id(FK)** here user table PK and post table FK are same

As per [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html),

**3)** This way we can get **benefit** of **NATURAL JOIN and JOIN with USING**

> Natural joins and joins with USING, including outer join variants, are
>   processed according to the SQL:2003 standard. The goal was to align
>   the syntax and semantics of MySQL with respect to NATURAL JOIN and
>   JOIN ... USING according to SQL:2003. However, these changes in join
>   processing can result in different output columns for some joins.
>   Also, some queries that appeared to work correctly in older versions
>   (prior to 5.0.12) must be rewritten to comply with the standard.

These changes have **five** main aspects:

1) The way that MySQL determines the result columns of NATURAL or USING join operations (and thus the result of the entire FROM clause).

2) Expansion of SELECT * and SELECT tbl_name.* into a list of selected columns.

3) Resolution of column names in NATURAL or USING joins.

4) Transformation of NATURAL or USING joins into JOIN ... ON.

5) Resolution of column names in the ON condition of a JOIN ... ON.

Examples:-

```
SELECT * FROM user NATURAL LEFT JOIN post;
SELECT * FROM user NATURAL JOIN post;
SELECT * FROM user JOIN post USING (user_id);
```