# What is the naming convention for Primary Key column?

Tags: database, database-design, naming-conventions, primary-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Primary key/foreign Key naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369593/primary-key-foreign-key-naming-convention)

What is the naming convention for Primary Key column in Db Tables?

For instance:
PK_Country or CountryId or ID or PrimaryKey or.. ?

Comment: Wrong site, go to dba.stackexchange.com. I think it was ask yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Columns should be named based on the data elements that they represent, not based on what constraints apply to them. A primary key column should be named in the same way you name any other column. The [ISO 11179 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_11179) has some useful guidelines for naming data elements.

Answer (score 4):

I like the Ruby on Rails conventions:

- primary key in any table is auto-increment integer column called `id`
- foreign keys are named as foreign table name plus `_id`.  Example:

  - `country_id` is a foreign key that corresponds to a record from the `countries` table

Comment: I tend to use this convention too (although I use PHP/Zend Framework), but what about tables with multiple foreign keys to the same table? **Example:** `order` has two columns referencing the same table `user`: who's the user that created the order and who's the user who approved.

Comment: You would have to break convention in that case, but I recommend using names that state the obvious, such as `creator_user_id` and `approver_user_id`, or `created_by` and `approved_by`.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but I couldn't get to stabilish a convention to this _convention-breaker_ need. :D

Comment: Using primary key with only id is good for active record or data mapping pattern, but it's can make you harder in making query like join. Joining the table with both same `id` you have to point out what `id` field belong to what table.

Answer (score 1):

If the table is called `Test` I would call the PK column `TestID`.

Comment: +1 - I would call it TEST_ID, not every RDBMS supports mixed case well.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty much up to the designer of the db. When I do it I make the field name of the primary key: id and field name of foreign keys: tablenameId

Answer (score 0):

I always try to start primary keys with PK and foriegn keys with FK. Also, when naming foriegn keys, I try to include the table names and column names in the name of the foriegn key:   FK_Questions-test-id_Tests-seq-num  would be a foriegn key from table questions to table tests where questinos.test_id = tests.seq_num.  i think it helps to name them that way for when you are glancing at your keys.

Answer (score 0):

There really is not a defined standard; rather, you should develop your own convention and make sure that every primary key you define is consistent with that convention.