# Backbone - using a different field name for id

Tags: backbone.js

I'm porting an old app to use backbone.js (hopefully)
Problem is none of the various objects in the system use 'id' for id -
each object is different. Reading around, I've come up with the solution below when initializing the Backbone.Model.

```
   initialize: function(){
    this.idAttribute = 'user_ID';
    this.set({'id':this.get('user_ID')});
 }
```

I'm worried however that as I develop with backbone this approach is gonna bite me.
Does anyone have any experience with this.
Any pointers much appreciated.

edit: I just called isNew() on the model and got true, even though the id is now set to 1. 
///////////////////////////////////////////

Using the following seems to sort it out.

```
User = Backbone.Model.extend({
idAttribute : 'user_ID'
```

})

Answer (score 49, accepted):

When you use idAttribute, backbone basically keeps the `id` property in sync with the `user_ID` property.  The way it's normally used is when you define your class

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'user_ID',
    initialize: function() {
        //do stuff
    }
});

var me = new UserModel({user_ID: 1234, name: 'Tim'});
console.log(me.id); //1234
console.log(me.get('user_ID')); //1234
console.log(me.isNew()); //false

var me2 = new UserModel({name: 'newUser'});
console.log(me2.isNew()); //true
```

Good Luck

Comment: Just stumbled upon this when I asked myself the question If should use id-suffixes like "id_user" instead of "id" in my relational database schema for a backbone project. I got convinced that it's better to use them according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1369773/2236166) , then I thought "Doh, but the id fields for backbone models...", until I read this Q&A. Thanks!

Comment: A little obvious but don't use .get('id') unless you want the original id value (if you have one). Always use 'model.id'.