# SQL - is it better to call a column 'name' or 'client_name' when there will be similar tables with 'name' columns?

Tags: sql, relational-database, naming-conventions, naming

I'm building a relational database, and so many of my tables have 'name' columns. And they're all related to each other.

For example, a central column is the Client table, and the client can have multiple Customers, and each client has a name, and each customer has a name. And each customer will be subscribed to any number of Services, which also has a name.

So I can have a 'name' column on every table, or alternatively I can have 'client_name', 'customer_name', 'service_name' and so on. Which hypothetically would make joins easier.

What do you recommend?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Naming of ID columns in database tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208580/naming-of-id-columns-in-database-tables)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you go to join two or more of these tables, you can (and probably should) use table *aliases* when referring to the individual columns.  So, there is no chance anyway of the column `name` on one table being confounded with `name` from another table.  That being said, I also recommend using the shorter version because it makes the labelling of each individual table more concise and readable.  Calling a column in the `client` table `client_name` is redundant, and doesn't add any useful information.