# What is a proper naming convention for MySQL FKs?

Tags: mysql, naming-conventions, foreign-keys

Being that they must be unique, what should I name FK's in a MySQL DB?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199498/foreign-key-naming-scheme

Answer (score 183, accepted):

In MySQL, there is no need to give a symbolic name to foreign key constraints. If a name is not given, InnoDB creates a unique name automatically.

In any case, this is the convention that I use:

```
fk_[referencing table name]_[referenced table name]_[referencing field name]
```

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id    int,
    name       varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE messages(
    message_id int,
    user_id    int
);

ALTER TABLE messages ADD CONSTRAINT fk_messages_users_user_id 
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id);
```

I try to stick with the same field names in referencing and referenced tables, as in `user_id` in the above example. When this is not practical, I also append the referenced field name to the foreign key name.

This naming convention allows me to "guess" the symbolic name just by looking at the table definitions, and in addition it also guarantees unique names.

Comment: The reason for creating a symbolic name is for referencing when you want/need to drop the constraint.  Oracle & SQL Server allow you to disable specific constraints.  If you don't have fk in the name, you have to confirm the constraint is a foreign key constraint...

Comment: What I like to do is use a double underscore between the referencing table name and the referenced table name.  This gives you the dual advantages of alphabetical listings keeping all of a table's FKs together and at the same time helping you avoid name collisions/confusion when there are multiple word table names.  I also omit the field part of the name when it is trivial (i.e. a single int field references the identity PK of another table).

Comment: What if there are more than 1 foreign key? Example: `member_id` ~> link to the table member, `edited_id` ~> foreign key for edited user , also link to table member. How should i name them?

Comment: @TomSawyer: I add 'pk_' to all foreign keys, followed by the referenced table (e.g. 'members'), followed by the usage/sense (e.g. 'editor' or 'author'). So I have something like 'pk_members_author' or 'pk_members_editor'.

Comment: What if the name is too long?

Answer (score 36):

my choice is different.
in my opinion, a table should have an `id` field, not a `user_id` one, because table is just called `user`, so:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
   id    int,
   name       varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE messages(
   id int,
   user_id    int
);
```

`user_id` in `messages` table is a fk field so it has to make clear which id is (`user_id`).

a fully-self-explaining naming convention, in my opinion, could be:

```
fk_[referencing table name]_[referencing field name]_[referenced table name]_[referenced field name]

i.e.: `fk_messages_user_id_users_id`
```

note:

- you can, in some case, omit the second element ([referencing field name])
- this fk could is unique, because if a `messages_user` table exists, the referencing field name should be `user_id` (and not just `id`) and the fk name should be:

  `fk_messages_user_user_id_users_id`

in other words, a foreign key naming convention make you sure about unique names if you also use a "referencing/referenced field" naming convention (and you can choose your own, of course).

Comment: Names have a way of persisting across code. Eventually, you'll find an `$id` variable somewhere with no idea which table it belongs to. The older your code base is and the more people have worked on it, the more likely this becomes.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't find yourself referencing fk's that often after they are created, one option is to keep it simple and let MySQL do the naming for you (as [Daniel Vassallo mentions in the beginning of his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2240991/1048805)).

While you won't be able to uniquely "guess" the constraint names with this method - you can easily find the foreign key constraint name by running a query:

```
use information_schema;
select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME from KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db_schema_name' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
```

For example you might receive the following from the query:

```
+------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | CONSTRAINT_NAME | REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME | REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME |
+------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| note       | taskid      | note_ibfk_2     | task                  | id                     |
| note       | userid      | note_ibfk_1     | user                  | id                     |
| task       | userid      | task_ibfk_1     | user                  | id                     |
+------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

If this extra step isn't too much for you, then you should be able to easily find the fk you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
fk-[referencing_table]-[referencing_field]
```

The reason is the combination of `referencing_table` and `referencing_field` is unique in a database.
This way make the foreign key name easy to read, for example:

```
table `user`:
    id
    name
    role

table `article`:
    id
    content
    created_user_id /* --> user.id */
    reviewed_user_id /* --> user.id */
```

So we have two foreign keys:

```
fk-article-created_user_id
fk-article-reviewed_user_id
```

Adding `user` table name to foreign key name is reduntdant.

Comment: What if the database name is `user_role`? `user` and `role` have manytomany relationship and `user_role` is the table that contains all the foreign key. Should it be `fk_user_role_role`?

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm fk-user_role-role