# Create a stored procedure to insert new data into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure to insert a new row in a table 'dbo.Terms'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.terms 
       @Term_en                      NVARCHAR(50)  = NULL   , 
       @Createdate                   DATETIME      = NULL   , 
       @Writer                       NVARCHAR(50)  = NULL   , 
       @Term_Subdomain               NVARCHAR(50)  = NULL  
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON 

     INSERT INTO dbo.terms
          (                    
            Term_en                     ,
            Createdate                  ,
            Writer                      ,
            Term_Subdomain                 
          ) 
     VALUES 
          ( 
            @Term_en    = 'Cat'               ,
            @Createdate   = '2013-12-12'      ,
            @Writer         = 'Fadi'          ,
            @Term_Subdomain = 'English'                    
          ) 

END 

GO
```

But is shows me an error here ( @Term_en    = 'Cat') incorrect syntax
Any help?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do there?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I presume you want to insert the values cat etc into the table; to do that you need to use the values from your procedures variables. I wouldn't call your procedure the same name as your table it will get all kinds of confusing; you can find some good resources for naming standards (or crib from [Adventureworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593582/database-naming-conventions-by-microsoft))

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.terms 
       @Term_en                      NVARCHAR(50)  = NULL   , 
       @Createdate                   DATETIME      = NULL   , 
       @Writer                       NVARCHAR(50)  = NULL   , 
       @Term_Subdomain               NVARCHAR(50)  = NULL  
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON 

     INSERT INTO dbo.terms
          (                    
            Term_en                     ,
            Createdate                  ,
            Writer                      ,
            Term_Subdomain                 
          ) 
     VALUES 
          ( 
            @Term_en,
            @Createdate,
            @Writer,
            @Term_Subdomain
          ) 

END 

GO
```

And to test it

```
exec dbo.terms 
    @Term_en    = 'Cat'               ,
    @Createdate   = '2013-12-12'      ,
    @Writer         = 'Fadi'          ,
    @Term_Subdomain = 'English'
```

Comment: @MartinSmith I think that depends how you call your procedures out of your application, If you are always able to pass all parameters over when you call a procedure then you don't need defaults. If your code calls procedures and sometimes don't have values to pass over for all variables the parameters you do need the null otherwise the procedure will expect you to pas the null into the variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now. can anyone tell me how to create a trigger to add a rows in another table when any new rows has inserted in a table 'dbo.terms'?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to set your defaults for parameters in your proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.terms 
       @Term_en        NVARCHAR(50)  = 'Cat', 
       @Createdate     DATETIME      = '2013-12-12', 
       @Writer         NVARCHAR(50)  = 'Fadi', 
       @Term_Subdomain NVARCHAR(50)  = 'English'
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON 

     INSERT INTO dbo.terms
          (                    
            Term_en                     ,
            Createdate                  ,
            Writer                      ,
            Term_Subdomain                 
          ) 
     VALUES 
          ( 
            @Term_en,
            @Createdate,
            @Writer,
            @Term_Subdomain                    
          ) 

END 

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct.
You put value in insert part. You should enter value in execution part

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE  dbo.terms     
   @Term_en                      NVARCHAR(50)  = NULL   ,    
   @Createdate                   DATETIME      = NULL   ,     
   @Writer                       NVARCHAR(50)  = NULL   ,    
   @Term_Subdomain               NVARCHAR(50)  = NULL
AS  
BEGIN  
 SET NOCOUNT ON  
 INSERT INTO dbo.terms  
      (                    
        Term_en,  
        Createdate,  
        Writer,
        Term_Subdomain                 
      )

 VALUES 
      ( 
        @Term_en    ,
        @Createdate ,
        @Writer     ,
        @Term_Subdomain                     
      ) 

 END
```

execute by this

```
exec dbo.terms 
@Term_en    = 'Cat'               ,
@Createdate   = '2013-12-12'      ,
@Writer         = 'Fadi'          ,
@Term_Subdomain = 'English' 

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      xxxx 
-- Create date: xx-xx-xxxx
-- Description: Procedure for Inserting Data in table 
-- =============================================


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Emp_Insert]
(
@Empname nvarchar(250)=null,
@Status int=null,
@LoginUserId nvarchar(50)=null,
@Msg nvarchar(MAX)=null OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN TRY

    INSERT INTO tbl_Employee
    VALUES
    (
    @Empname ,
    @Status,
    GETDATE(),
    GETDATE(),
    @LoginUserId
    )

    SET @Msg='Table Detail Saved Successfully.'

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    SET @Msg=ERROR_MESSAGE()

END CATCH

GO
```