# Insert new data to a table with stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I tried to make a stored procedure the insert data to a table:

```
create procedure AddEmployee
(
    @FirstName nvarchar(20)
    , @LastName nvarchar(20)
    , @BirthDate datetime
    , @Country nvarchar(15)
    , @City nvarchar(15)
)
as
    insert into Employees
    values (@FirstName, @LastName, @BirthDate, @Country, @City)
go
```

But when I run it I get the error message:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AddEmployee, Line 2 [Batch Start Line 17]
> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I looked at this question but it didn't solve my problem:
[Create a stored procedure to insert new data into a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544752/create-a-stored-procedure-to-insert-a-new-data-in-a-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using insert, *always* include the columns names:

```
create procedure AddEmployee (
    @FirstName nvarchar(20) ,
    @LastName nvarchar(20) ,
    @BirthDate datetime,
    @Country nvarchar(15),
    @City nvarchar(15)
) as
begin
    insert into Employees (FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, Country, City)
        values (@FirstName, @LastName, @BirthDate, @Country, @City);
end;
```

Although SQL allows you to leave out the column names, you should include them as a best-practice.  This is particularly important for those learning the language, so they learn the safer way to do things.

Comment: don't forget the opening parenthesis after the `insert into` ..

Comment: @Jason . . . I don't know what you mean.  The only parentheses are around the column list and the values list.

Comment: my bad ... I was reading employees as a column name ... :)