# Why do we set the "Property" in stored procedure mapping in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am a novice in EF6. I defined a SP with variables of the input type. In the SP specifies which variable is associated with which column. Then, why do we set the "Property" in stored procedure mapping? Differ?
[image: Sp Mapping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats happening is that there is a mapping from the `SQL` type to the `.NET` type.

`.NET` has different types than `SQL` has.

You can find a list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings).

The entity framework will handle the conversions for you.

Here's a part of the table:

```
SQL Server Database Engine type         .NET Framework type         SqlDbType 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bigint                                 Int64                        BigInt        
binary                                 Byte[]                       VarBinary 
bit                                    Boolean                      Bit       
char                                   String                       Char      
date 1                                 DateTime                     Date 1        
datetime                               DateTime                     DateTime      
datetime2                              DateTime                     DateTime2
```

As for the naming of the property: EF has some (sometimes annoying) naming conventions.

More on that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/built-in

And here: [Database Naming Conventions by Microsoft?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593582/database-naming-conventions-by-microsoft)

Take special note to:

> "Do not prefix stored procedures with sp_, because this prefix is reserved for identifying system-stored procedures."

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robcaron/2005/01/27/prefixing-stored-procedure-names-with-sp_/