# Bracket around database name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I want to use one of my databases, I should to write this query:

`USE DatabaseName;`

but when I was trying to type this query my SQL Prompt use the correct form of this query which that query is this:

`USE [DataBases]`

What does this bracket means in this query or in SQL Server queries?

This query is also correct

```
USE DatabaseName;
```

but I want to know what the meaning of brackets in SQL Server is or in same queries?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Same as backticks in mysql, double quotes in teradata and others. As an added benefit , it allows you to stomp all over best practices and use reserved words and such as object names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you have SQL keyword, space or any other illegal characters then you need to use square brackets.
2. SQL server parse and compiler much more easy to validate and compile code.
3. code search tools easy to find table names or column names only.

Comment: When a duplicate exists, please vote to close as a duplicate rather than re-answering again.

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets are meant to let you treat an object name which would normally not be allowed, as a valid object name. Things like special characters, spaces, and reserved keywords are some good examples.

```
select [Column with spaces], [1NumberAtTheStart]
from dbo.[User]
```

If not for square brackets here, none of the quoted objects above would pass as valid object names. The first column has spaces, the second starts with a number, and User is a reserved keyword.

The reason SQLPrompt suggests not using them is that it can make your code look "noisy".

Of course, some times you *need* them. Say you have a table called `dbo.User`. If you try to say `select * from dbo.User` you will get an error. So you MUST quote the object name to keep SQL from freaking out (i.e. `select * from dbo.[user]`). It's completely *allowable* in SQL to quote all your object names if you really want, but it's really meant for if you have object names with spaces, or other characters you need to ignore.

Comment: Could you give me some article about convention for naming database and tables and fileds ?

Comment: This is a pretty good summary of the [suggested best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593582/database-naming-conventions-by-microsoft). At a minimum, no spaces in object names, and no numbers at the start of object names. Pretty much, if your object name _requires_ you to square bracket it - rethink it. There are other guideline around casing, underscores, pluralization etc. which are more subjective. The article above does a good job making sound recommendations for those too.

Comment: It is not considered 'bad form' to capitalize keywords. I'm not sure where you came up with that. Capitalizing keywords actually makes your code **more** readable in all honesty. Many code helpers, like SQL Prompt, will do this for you by default.

Comment: Agree to disagree. Everyone I have ever spoken to has said they find full uppercasing keywords obnoxious. With code highlighting, it becomes less important to use capitalization to identify keywords. But I will grant that there may be people who prefer it. Updating my answer.

Comment: When a duplicate exists, please vote to close as a duplicate rather than re-answering again.