# Error: Duplicate foreign key constraint name

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I exported a schema from workbench and now trying to use that script to create table in my server, But getting error

I tried to change the table and also tried to find duplicate foriegn key.

ERROR 1826: Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'bank_id'
SQL Statement:

---

-- Table `aditya`.`users_has_bank`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aditya`.`users_has_bank` (
  `users_user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bank_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`users_user_id`),
  INDEX `bank_id_idx` (`bank_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `user_id_idx` (`user_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `bank_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`bank_id`)
    REFERENCES `aditya`.`bank` (`bank_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `aditya`.`users` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: add more detail about all the steps, put your script as well.

Answer (score -2):

High possibility that FK name is used in other tables within your schema. Please do practice good FK naming convention

Source: [Foreign Key naming scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199498/foreign-key-naming-scheme)